# Issue with php artisan migrate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have problem with php artisan migrate. I use as root and the response is following:

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = cms and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

What I have to make to resolve this issue?

*edit 1*

I check my .env file and configure it

When i use:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan migrate:instal
```

it gaves me request:

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
```

and it is my .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=cms
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=gaMoJVnwXp
```

I thought that is issue that I didn't make table migrations, but it also didn't work. I also tried to enable pdo file in php.ini, but it also didn't work. When I make php artisan migrate I have to have empty database or with table called migrations?

edit 2
Okay, I've almost done it. It supposed that I had issues with sql configuration. I reinstalled the mysql server and now I can use mysql command. Now I have problem with php artisan migrate - i don't have any tracebacks, but it looks like it's loading continuously. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you connect to the database through the console?

Answer (score 1):

Please check and configure your .env correctly!

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

If it still does not work try this

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan migrate:install
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')